# Excel - matching any of multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Is it possible to use IFERROR or a similar function to match ANY value found in multiple reference columns, in other words with the OR operator? So far I've only found tutorials on how to make this work with the AND operator, i.e. matching ALL values from a particular row.

Say this is what I have on reference sheet:

```
     A   B   C
1   1a1 a1A aa1
2   1b1 b1b BB1
3   1c1 c1c Cc1
```

This is the matching sheet:

```
     A   Match? 
1   a1A    Y
2   BB1    Y
3   1z1    N
```

If A1 matches ANY of the values on reference sheet, then return some value like Y.

Comment: It appears that you may have duplicate user accounts.  You should visit the [contact form](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’.

Answer (score 3):

Use COUNTIF inside an IF()

```
=IF(COUNTIF(ReferenceSheet!$A$1:$C$3,A1),"Y","N")
```